# how to hide any UIView after applying setFrame property

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, subview

I have view  which add as subView in View in view did load method it works fine but after setFrame property of that view in method then if i hide that view then it does not hide,i think due to setFrame property it is not hiding the view.

```
      NineView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(570,300,50,-height9)];

  NineView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(102/255.f) green:(107/255.f) blue:(40/255.f) alpha:1];

  [self.view addSubview:NineView];
```

and after setFrame if i hide this view then it is not hiding it

```
            [NineView setFrame:CGRectMake(570,300,50,-height9)];
```

Comment: where is your hide view coding

Comment: @Jdeveloper Iphone Are you thr ?

Comment: Why are you using "initWithFrame" method and then , "setFrame" method ? both methods result into same thing. 
Also ..please paste some more code, so that we can understand better about what exactly you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NineView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(570,300,50,-height9)];
NineView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:(102/255.f) green:(107/255.f) blue:(40/255.f) alpha:1];
[self.view addSubview:NineView];
[NineView setHidden:YES];
```

Should hide your view just fine.

EDIT: Also, you X-coordinate of the view will place your view out of the screen bounds. 
It should be less than 320. Since maximum width of iPhone is 320 and height is 480. 
For iPhone5 height is 568.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide after `setFrame` method and you are doing one thing is wrong your `X coordinate` is out of 320 So you can't see your view because it is out of the screen bounds. And Write this code in your method where do you wanna hide this view.If you can't hide it means you are doing something wrong in your code.

```
[NineView setHidden:YES];
```

**Note** : In iPhone 4

```
   X coordinate should be x >= 0 and  x <= 320
   Y coordinate should be y >= 0 and  y <= 480
```

In iPhone 5

```
   X coordinate should be x >= 0 and  x <= 320
   Y coordinate should be y >= 0 and  y <= 568
```